# Why was this question about Alexa off-topic (and how can I write it better)?

Tags: discussion, support

I deleted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1339049/is-there-any-way-to-control-alexas-music-selection-without-voice-for-multi-room), after it was downvoted and closed as off-topic***.

That's totally fine, I respect the wisdom of those who are smarter and more experienced with this SE site ( @[keltari](https://superuser.com/users/94133/keltari) , @[jakegould](https://superuser.com/users/167207/jakegould) et al -- thank you).

However, for me to improve I need to understand why. Based on the close message and linked documentation it sounded right on topic to me (it's about how to use software to control hardware... no?).

I noticed that there were no tags for Alexa, Echo, Google Home, etc. Is it just that these voice controlled devices are kind of unofficially off-topic? It seemed that way to me, but I'm guessing that's not the real answer and there's something I can learn here to be a better SuperUser user.

Thanks! Wasn't sure if the best tag for this is "discussion" or "support" so I added both - please feel free to edit.

*** for anyone who can't see the text of the deleted question I linked to, it was basically this:*

> I have an Android phone and multiple Echo dots and for some reason the
>   voice recognition on Alexa does not work as well when issuing
>   multi-room music commands... [technical details went here, omitted for
>   brevity]... as a workaround, is there any way to control the music
>   selection without voice for multi-room music? I only know how to do it
>   for one device at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the help centre ["on-topic" page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) media devices and smartphones are off-topic here.

> and it is not about …
>
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - **electronic devices**, media players, **cell phones** or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer**,

Basically this is not a problem with your computer nor about hardware interfacing with a laptop or desktop computer. Tablets running iOS or Android are considered "large smartphones" in this context.

If it is a problem with using Android devices (smartphones etc.) then there is [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I see, thank you much. OK so maybe I head to Area 51 if there's not a SE site for the VR controlled IoT devices as well

Comment: @Hack-R to address your (now deleted) comment... a smartphone or Alexa device may have a CPU, but they are not considered "general purpose" computing devices. The software on them is largely locked down, limited, or otherwise not on "open" platforms meaning that you cannot run a substantively different system on them without a lot of hacking about and different Android versions and variants don't count. There was a [Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) Area51 proposal years ago, but it didn't survive. Maybe some variant of that would do better now...